# Why does this prod_ render in Jupyter but as PDF with texlive?

Tags: math-mode, errors, texlive-2018

In a Jupyter notebook, I have

```
$$P' = \prod_\nolimits{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{(s-i)}{s}$$
```

which renders correctly (to me) in Jupyter as

[image]

When I render the notebook as PDF, I get this on the console:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \nolimits 
l.558 \[P' = \prod_\nolimits
                            {i=0}^{m-1} \frac{(s-i)}{s}\]
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \nolimits 
l.558 \[P' = \prod_\nolimits
                            {i=0}^{m-1} \frac{(s-i)}{s}\]
```

I can't tell what's wrong and and various attempts to wrap prod_ arguments in {} have not been successful.

I'm using texlive 2018.20190227-1 from Ubuntu 19.04 and jupyter 4.4.0.

Comment: The correct syntax is `$$P' = \prod\nolimits_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{(s-i)}{s}$$`. In Jupyter it works because Jupyter doesn't use a proper TeX engine to render it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: That's it @PhelypeOleinik. If you write as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Reece Done! Reading your question again I notice you say `\prod_`, so (forgive me if I'm wrong) I think you understand `\prod_` as an operator. The operator is actually just `\prod`. The `_` symbol in TeX (usually) indicates that what follows is the lower limit of the operator (or subscript) and the `^` is the same for the upper limit (or the superscript), and they can be given in any order (for example `\prod_a^b` and `\prod^b_a` both produce the same) or not at all (for example `\prod_a` or `\prod^b` or even just `\prod` are all valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jupyter uses MathJax](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.html) to render the formulas you type, and it is a well known fact that MathJax tries to emulate the behaviour of TeX but it just can't because it's not TeX, so some things that should not work end up working by accident (or not) and the other way around as well.

MathJax allows you to put `\nolimits` anywhere after the operator. All of these are valid in MathJax (tested at http://math.stackexchange.com):

[image]

However *The TeXBook* says (emphasis mine):

> You can change TeX's convention by simply typing `\limits` or `\nolimits` **immediately after the large operator**. For example,
>
> [image]

So the correct form is `$$P' = \prod\nolimits_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{(s-i)}{s}$$`